# Can't run Wine application on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, wine

**Does anyone know what is wrong with my WineHQ application or my ubuntu configuration? I use Ubuntu 20.04 (x86_64).**

I followed all the steps from WineHQ [setup tutorial](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) to use binary packages, also I have tried to build WineHQ from source files. I even cross-checked myself with a guy on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wx8NbZEAPNM&t=200s).

In each case, WineHQ installs successfully but fails to run, always with the same output:

```
$ winecfg
0084:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0084:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0084:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0084:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
0048:err:explorer:initialize_display_settings Failed to query current display settings for L"\\\\.\\DISPLAY1".
0048:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
0048:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow L"The explorer process failed to start."
0048:err:systray:initialize_systray Could not create tray window
00f8:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.
00f8:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow L"The graphics driver is missing. Check your build!"
```

Thank you for your help and attention)

*P.S. Wine has been installed successfully, I have a problem only with the boot*

```
$ wine --version
wine-7.19
```

*P.S.S. I really hope that you will help me and will not give me minuses)*

Comment: Sounds like a very good question to ask Wine support. They are the experts on Wine.

Comment: @David, I was hoping that someone has already come across and can show an obvious solution, since, to be honest, most likely I blunted it somewhere. But thank you, this is very good advice.

Comment: I just meet this problem in Mint based on Ubuntu jammy and I find it might because I open the noninteger scaling in Display Setting.
Hope it can help you~